# Serializing `std::type_index`

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I've been using `std::type_index` to store a `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, MyProperty>` in `MyClass`. Now I would like to serialize (with boost::serialization) `MyClass`. The compiler says `struct std::type_index has no member named serialize` which indicates that boost::serialization doesn't support `std::type_index`. So the question is, what to do in this case? Does anyone have a `serialize` function for `std::type_index`? Or is there a different object that can be used for the key for this `map` that I need that is already serializable that can do the same type of thing. Namely, when using a function template I do :

```
template <typename T>
void MyClass::func(T)
{
  myMap.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
}
```

Here is a demo of the lack of support:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <typeindex>

int main()
{
    std::type_index myTypeIndex = typeid(double);

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

    outputArchive << myTypeIndex;
    outputStream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Danger. minefield ahead. You will want to index on something you can construct, not something that is constructed by the compiler. Unfortunately you'll need to create your own polymorphic, serialisable wrapper around typeid.

Comment: @RichardHodges You're saying using `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, ...>` in general is a bad idea? Or only when it will need to be serialized?

Comment: no, type_index is designed to be used as an index as you are doing. It's just not compatible with boost::serialize because you don't control construction. You;ll at the least have to provide custom load/store functions for it.

Comment: @RichardHodges I was thinking of just switching to `std::unordered_map<MyEnum, ...>` and providing a function `MyEnum TypeToEnum(type_index)` - any problem with that?

Comment: I think if you're going to do surgery, I would be inclined to do it where there is least damage to overall efficiency and succinctness. If type_index is the best key-type for the job I would leave it there, and simply write some custom code for serialisation - since this only impacts the program in one place.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder whether it would be possible to write a load/save function for std::type_index... will have a think

Comment: ...answer not finished yet... just showing you the idea

Comment: ok. answer complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Define your own `boost::serialization::load/save<>` overloads for std::type_index

Step 2: provide a means of mapping strings to type_index and vice-versa.

Step 3: store the type_index in the archive in terms of its name.

You will of course need to remember to register the name of every type you intend to use as a key in your map. In the example below you would do this by calling `register_name("Foo", typeid(Foo));` etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct nothing {};

using named_typeindex = std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index>;
std::vector<named_typeindex> name_register =
{
};

std::type_index type_for_name(const std::string& name)
{
    auto i = std::find_if(std::begin(name_register), std::end(name_register),
                          [&name](const auto& entry) { return std::get<std::string>(entry) == name; } );
    if (i == std::end(name_register))
        return typeid(nothing);
    return std::get<std::type_index>(*i);
}

std::string const& name_for_type(std::type_index type)
{
    auto i = std::find_if(std::begin(name_register), std::end(name_register),
                          [type](const auto& entry) { return std::get<std::type_index>(entry) == type; } );

    using namespace std::string_literals;
    if (i == std::end(name_register))
        throw std::logic_error("unregistered type "s + type.name());

    return std::get<std::string>(*i);
}

bool register_name(std::string name, std::type_index ti)
{
    if (type_for_name(name) == typeid(nothing))
    {
        name_register.push_back(std::make_tuple(std::move(name), ti));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {

        template<class Archive>
        void save(Archive & ar, const std::type_index & t, unsigned int version)
        {
            ar << name_for_type(t);
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void load(Archive & ar, std::type_index & t, unsigned int version)
        {
            std::string s;
            ar >> s;
            t = type_for_name(s);
        }

    } // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(std::type_index);

int main()
{
    std::type_index myTypeIndex = typeid(double);

    std::ostringstream outputStream {};
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);

    outputArchive << myTypeIndex;

    std::cout << outputStream.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```